# SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase in BaseAdapter fails but openOrCreateDatabase works fine in Activity

Tags: android

I create my database in the onCreate method of an Activity.  In this Activity I can add records and I can query records.  If there are records that result from my query I add them to a custom ListView, hence the BaseAdapter class.  The ListView contains two TextViews and a Delete Button.  When the button is clicked I'd like to be able to remove a record from the database, but I cannot seem to open the database.  I am trying to open the database like so ...

```
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(com.red.myApp.Utils.database_name, null, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

... this fails with this in the logcat ...

```
09-19 21:56:15.825: I/Database(4773): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
09-19 21:56:15.825: E/Database(4773): sqlite3_open_v2("BookMarksV20.db", &handle, 2, NULL) failed
```

So what's the deal? Is just plain impossible to use SQLite in type of class other than a Activity or a Service?  What am I doing wrong here?

Thank for taking a look :)

Comment: Just be sure that you are using one instance of database and before using that open database...

Comment: Thanks OmSai, but how do I do that?  Everytime I access the database in my Activity I do `openOrCreateDataBase (...)` and `db.close()`.  So I do not think there are any other "instances" of the database. Of course I am not really sure what you mean by "instance".

Comment: Use an appropriate implementation of `SQLiteHelper` and that will automatically handle db creation & db opening while calling `getWritableDatabase()`/`getReadableDatabase()`

Comment: How can I determine what the appropriate implementation of `SQLifeHelper` is?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is useful to you.you have to put this code in your create() in activity.

```
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    dbHelper.createDataBase();
    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.openDataBase();
```